# unable to read browser cookie in python

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I have an application which need to check if the browser had a cookie called "RSOSESSION", i tried reading it via

```
request.session.get('RSOSESSION');
```

Its always coming as 'None', where as i can see a value in the browser using firebug.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use [request.COOKIES](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.COOKIES)

```
>>> 'RSOSESSION' in request.COOKIES
True
```

Comment: from django.shortcuts import render, HttpResponse


def index(request):
    return HttpResponse('SMSESSION' in request.cookies)

Comment: its throwing 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'cookies'

Comment: Its `request.COOKIES`

Comment: I was able to connect but look like the variable is not present. But i do see it in browser cookies

Comment: I m able to see the information in the browser, but not when i call request.COOKIES. what might be the reason?